# Developing a Outlook Web Add in using .NET Core which can do interprocess communication

Tags: c#, .net-core, outlook

I am working on developing an Outlook web plugin for Office 365 online in .NET Core.

I have a COM based service running on the machine. My requirement is to be able to communicate from the Outlook plugin code (java script Ajax) to the COM service.

If it were not for .NET Core, I would have developed a WCF service which could have performed as a middle layer between the web plugin and COM service.

But in .NET Core we do not have WCF which can be used for this purpose.

Can you suggest what I can do to achieve this in .NET Core?

My Requirement is:

Outlook Web Plugin => Communicates with some service running on local machine => the service communicates with COM based service running on the machine.

Comment: TCPClient/ TCPListener?

Comment: In a web JS addin, you are pretty much limited to communicating with the server through http if the COM component is designed to serve as a web server and is running and listening to the incoming requests.

Comment: Yes, Im exploring developing a web API hosted in windows service which can interact with the Outlook web plugin on the same machine. From within the Web API  I can make COM calls to my another COM based service.

Comment: Can we host .NET Core Web API as Windows Service? Or it should be an MVC web application to host into windows service?

Comment: looks like ASP.NET Core Web API cannot be hosted in a Windows Service. The Web API builds into a DLL and not EXE. The Windows service needs EXE to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar inter-process communication problem, I chose Visual Studio open source JSON RPC implementation: https://github.com/microsoft/vs-streamjsonrpc

It works well, and should be compatible with a lot of different environments and platforms!